# ggplot2: How to get a Geom Class to affect ScaleContinuous Class

Tags: r, ggplot2, environment, reference-class

I have begun to extend `ggplot2` and I'm still getting a feel for how the package calls all of its internal functions.

I have a new ggproto class that extends one of the current `Geom` environments. The current model of the class will plot something along the discrete x axis, ideally touching the x axis ticks. This model works well when the y axis is already on a discrete scale, because the default expansion values only adds .6 padding. However on a continuous y scale, the default padding can make these new plotted objects seem far.
In summary, how can I make my `Geom` class override the default expansion without just adding either `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0,.05,0)` or `scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0, .6,0)` to my layer function...

Consider the following reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
mtcars0 <- as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = "CarNames") %>%
  gather(key = "qualities", value = "value", -CarNames) %>%
  group_by(qualities) %>%
  mutate(scaledValue = scale(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(carCase = case_when(str_detect(CarNames, "^[A-M]") ~ "A-M",
                             TRUE ~ "N-Z"))
"%||%" <- function(a, b) {
  if (!is.null(a)) a else b
}

MyText <- ggproto("GeomMyText",
                  GeomText,
                  extra_params = c("na.rm","padDist"),
                  setup_data = function(data, params){
                    #find bottom of plot with sufficent space
                    minpadding <- params$padDist %||% diff(range(data$y))*.05
                    data$y <- min(data$y) - minpadding
                    data 
                  })

geom_mytext <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
                         ..., parse = FALSE, nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0, check_overlap = FALSE, 
                         na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, padDist = NULL) 
{ 
  if (!missing(nudge_x) || !missing(nudge_y)) {
    if (!missing(position)) {
      abort("You must specify either `position` or `nudge_x`/`nudge_y`.")
    }
    position <- position_nudge(nudge_x, nudge_y)
  }
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = MyText, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(parse = parse, check_overlap = check_overlap, 
                      na.rm = na.rm, padDist = padDist, ...))
}


result <- ggplot(mtcars0, aes(x = CarNames, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_mytext(aes(label = carCase)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
#Default
result 
#Desired Result without having to call scale_y_continuous
result + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0,0.05,0))
```

I'm assuming I need to extend the `ScaleContinuous` environment but I have no idea how to connect the `MyText` environment with it.

Any suggestions?

---- EDIT ----

Thanks for the quick replies!
A few things -

1. I am aware there is over plotting and clipping of labels, this isn't my actual Geom environment, just something I could put together that demonstrates my question.
2. As I was afraid, it seems that everyone so far is providing the [solution that was raised for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580425/ggplot2-how-to-get-a-geom-class-to-affect-scalecontinuous-class). While supplying my own scale is less than ideal - because I have to put logic in to discern if they associated y axis is discrete/continuous, when `ggplot2` already knows this, I figured that there might be a trick I was missing. For now I will continue development with the suggestions given. Thanks!

---- EDIT 2 ----

I took another look at the [solution given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580425/ggplot2-how-to-get-a-geom-class-to-affect-scalecontinuous-class). The exact parameters I need to modify is

```
panel_params$y$continuous_range[1] <- panel_params$y$limits[1]
```

And I need to do this somewhere in `draw_panel`. It seems like the associated scales are contained there and the `coord$transform(data, panel_params)` is responsible for including the padding on the rescaled axis depending on what is set for `panel_params$y$limits` and `panel_params$y$continuous_range`.

Thanks again to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 2):

Nice question - thanks for posting.

This is easier than you'd think. You simply bundle the desired scale object with the layer object that is returned from your `geom_mytext` function by concatenating them with `c`. In this example I have also bundled a `coord_cartesian` object so that I could turn clipping off to show the text properly. I have also changed the default `check.overlap` to `TRUE` because your labels are being overplotted.

Note I haven't changed your `ggplot` call at all

```
geom_mytext <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
                         ..., parse = FALSE, nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0, check_overlap = FALSE, 
                         na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, padDist = NULL) 
{ 
  if (!missing(nudge_x) || !missing(nudge_y)) {
    if (!missing(position)) {
      abort("You must specify either `position` or `nudge_x`/`nudge_y`.")
    }
    position <- position_nudge(nudge_x, nudge_y)
  }
  c(layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = MyText, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(parse = parse, check_overlap = check_overlap, 
                      na.rm = na.rm, padDist = padDist, ...)), 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0,0.05,0)),
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off"))
}


result <- ggplot(mtcars0, aes(x = CarNames, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_mytext(label = "test") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))

result
```

[image]

Now come the caveats. Because you are supplying your own `scale_y_continuous` object, users won't like that ggplot complains when they try to add their own y scale. You will also need some logic to choose between adding a continuous or discrete y scale. I don't think these are insurmountable problems though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Allan! I was asking this question for the very reason you mentioned - I was hoping there was a way for me to change defaults without supplying my own scale. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't generally recommend the route you are taking to achieve text at the bottom. The reason is that within the grammar of graphics paradigm, all different graphical elements (themes, coords, stats, facets, geoms) should all operate independently from oneanother. When I add a geom to a plot I expect the data to affect the scales but not the geom affecting the scales.

That said, here is the easiest way to automatically set the y-expansion with a geom, and that is to simply return a list of the geom and the scale from the constructor. This is similar to how `geom_sf()` automatically sets the `coord_sf()`. I know in your question you mention this is not how you like it, but there is just no natural infrastructure for geoms layers to communicate to the scales other than with data.

```
geom_mytext <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
                         ..., parse = FALSE, nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0, check_overlap = FALSE, 
                         na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, padDist = NULL) 
{ 
  if (!missing(nudge_x) || !missing(nudge_y)) {
    if (!missing(position)) {
      abort("You must specify either `position` or `nudge_x`/`nudge_y`.")
    }
    position <- position_nudge(nudge_x, nudge_y)
  }
  layer <- layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = MyText, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(parse = parse, check_overlap = check_overlap, 
                      na.rm = na.rm, padDist = padDist, ...))
  list(layer, scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0,0.05,0)))
}
```

What I'm recommending instead is to simply set `data$y <- -Inf`, which will be ignored by the scale training, leaving the default expansion factor intact but placing your data at the x-axis anyway.

```
MyText <- ggproto("GeomMyText",
                  GeomText,
                  extra_params = c("na.rm","padDist"),
                  setup_data = function(data, params){
                    data$y <- -Inf
                    data 
                  })
```

Which gives me this plot:

[image]

For comparison this is what your reprex plots for me:

[image]

As an aside, there seem to be a lot of duplicated labels, which you might want to adress in your final geom.

Comment: I thought this would be up your street teunbrand. It's nice to see an alternative to the "obvious" answer

Comment: Yeah I feel like answering these sort of questions are also good practice for me dealing with ggplot infrastructure. It was confusing as hell when I just started out though :)

Comment: Indeed. I have learned a lot about ggplot by answering questions here, and your answers always contain something new for me. Thank you.